# R Convert egor object to igraph/ use the visualization app (error: Duplicate vertex names)

Tags: r

I want to analyse egocentric networks using R's egor package. This package includes the egor's Network Visualization App - short egor_vis_app - (which uses igraph). I managed to create an egor object but I can't use this app to visualize the networks (error Duplicate vertex names) OR create an igraph objext (as_igraph(), same error). What am I doing wrong?

What I tried so far: 
I used the pre-existing egor object (data("egor32")) and the visualization app worked.

Then, I used this pre-existing data to create an egor object:

```
    data("alters32")
    data("egos32")
    data("edges32") 
    e <- egor(alters.df = alters32,
               egos.df = egos32,
               aaties = edges32,
               ID.vars = list(
                 ego = "egoID",
                 alter = "alterID",
                 source = "Source",
                 target = "Target"))
```

and the app as well as the as_igraph(e) function
don't work (I followed this [tutorial](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/egor/vignettes/using_egor.html) when creating the egor object with this data).

And this is my sample code (based on [this](https://github.com/tilltnet/egor/issues/15)):

```
    df_new <- read.csv(textConnection('"id","numgiven","sex",
    "sex1","sex2","sex3","sex4","sex5","close12",
    "close13","close14","close15","close23","close24",
    "close25","close34","close35","close45"
    10,6,1,2,2,1,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1
    36,6,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0'
    ), as.is=TRUE)

    e1 <- with(df_new,  onefile_to_egor(egos = df_new, pmin(numgiven,5), 
                           ID.vars=list(ego="id"), 
                           attr.start.col="sex1",
                           attr.end.col="sex5",
                           max.alters=5,
                           aa.first.var="close12", 
                           aa.regex="^(?<attr>[[:alpha:]]+)(?<src>[[:digit:]])(?<tgt>[[:digit:]])$"))
```

Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am one of the developers of egor, and while I am aware of this problem and there are plans to fix it in upcoming versions, there's a way to fix this yourself, by reordering the alter data columns. The problem is that igraph expects the alter IDs or vertex names to be the first column in the dataframe listing the alters/vertices.

Here is how you can fix your egor object:

```
library(dplyr)
e1$.alts <- lapply(e1$.alts, function(x) select(x, .altID, everything()))
```

With this fix in place the as_igraph() function and the visualization app should work.